# tell lsp-mode not to look for pyright

Tags: osx, lsp-mode

I'm trying to add type checking and code completion for python.  I'm using Emacs 28.2.

I installed pyright using brew (`brew install pyright`) and when I open a python file, I see: `Unable to find server ... the following servers could be installed automatically`
and it lists only `pyright`.  I press enter, expecting it to look for my installation of brew (which works in the shell).  Instead, I see this error:

> LSP :: Server pyright install process failed with the following error
> message: Unable to find a way to install pyright.

How can I tell lsp to use my working version of pyright instead of attempting to install a new one?

```
(setq shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")

(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)

;; gtd setup
(setq org-directory "~/org")
(setq org-agenda-files (list "inbox.org"))


(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c c") 'org-capture)

(defun org-capture-inbox ()
     (interactive)
     (call-interactively 'org-store-link)
     (org-capture nil "i"))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c i") 'org-capture-inbox)


;; react setup



(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
 (unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (package-install 'use-package))
  (require 'use-package)
  (setq use-package-always-ensure 't)


(setq package-selected-packages '(lsp-mode yasnippet lsp-treemacs helm-lsp projectile hydra flycheck company avy which-key helm-xref dap-mode zenburn-theme json-mode))
(when (cl-find-if-not #'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (mapc #'package-install package-selected-packages))
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(helm-mode)
(require 'helm-xref)
(define-key global-map [remap find-file] #'helm-find-files)
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] #'helm-M-x)
(define-key global-map [remap switch-to-buffer] #'helm-mini)
(which-key-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'lsp)
(setq gc-cons-threshold (* 100 1024 1024)
      read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)
      company-idle-delay 0.0
      company-minimum-prefix-length 1
      create-lockfiles nil) ;; lock files will kill `npm start'
(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (require 'dap-chrome)
  (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
  (yas-global-mode))


(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c a") 'org-agenda)
(setq org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp ".")

(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
        (todo   . " %i %-12:c")
        (tags   . " %i %-12:c")
        (search . " %i %-12:c")))

(setq org-agenda-prefix-format
      '((agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s")
        (todo   . " ")
        (tags   . " %i %-12:c")
        (search . " %i %-12:c")))


(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "IN PROGRESS" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED")))
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(emacsql org-roam lsp-pyright lsp-jedi lsp-mode yasnippet lsp-treemacs helm-lsp projectile hydra flycheck company avy which-key helm-xref dap-mode zenburn-theme json-mode)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin")
(use-package lsp-pyright
  :ensure t
  :hook (python-mode . (lambda ()
                          (require 'lsp-pyright)
                          (lsp))))  ; or lsp-deferred


(setq org-roam-directory (file-truename "~/org"))
(org-roam-db-autosync-mode)

;; org roam

(use-package org-roam
    :after org
    :init (setq org-roam-v2-ack t) ;; Acknowledge V2 upgrade
    :custom
    (org-roam-directory (file-truename org-directory))
    :config
    (org-roam-setup)
    :bind (("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
           ("C-c n r" . org-roam-node-random)           
           (:map org-mode-map
                 (("C-c n i" . org-roam-node-insert)
                  ("C-c n o" . org-id-get-create)
                  ("C-c n t" . org-roam-tag-add)
                  ("C-c n a" . org-roam-alias-add)
                  ("C-c n l" . org-roam-buffer-toggle)))))


(executable-find "pyright")
```

Here's what the lsp-buffer shows:

```
The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id pyright, priority 3)
Command "/opt/homebrew/bin/pyright-langserver --stdio" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Command "/opt/homebrew/bin/pyright-langserver --stdio" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
```

And here's what the `pyright::stderr` buffer shows:

```
env: node: No such file or directory

Process pyright stderr finished
env: node: No such file or directory
env: node: No such file or directory

Process pyright stderr<1> finished

Process pyright stderr finished
env: node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: make sure emacs can find `pyright` with `(executable-find "pyright")`

Comment: Are you also using `lsp-pyright`? Please share your Python and LSP mode config.

Comment: @TianshuWang  I added that to my `.emacs` file and it throws no errors when I open emacs

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas  I added my entire `.emacs` file, which is the only config I use.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You should test the `(executable-find "pyright")` using `M-:`, it won't throw an error if it doesn't find anything (instead it simply returns nil)

Comment: @dalanicolai. Okay, tested it and yes, it returns nil

Comment: okay, then now check the value of typing `which pyright` in a terminal. If it does show some path there, then you should fix your `exec-path` in Emacs. Do you use some Emacs distribution like Spacemacs/Doom etc.?

Comment: @dalanicolai. the value is `/opt/homebrew/bin/pyright`.  I did change some stuff in my init file in order to get my emacs to shell to behave like me mac shell.  In the first line of my init I set my shell to "bin/zsh" - could that have anything to do with it?  No, I don't use spacemacs/doom.

Comment: I'd take @dalanicolai up on his advice. Inspect your `exec-path` in emacs (`C-h v exec-path`) and tack on that bin directory if necessary somewhere in your init file before invoking pyright: `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin")`

Comment: Well, Emacs should 'inherit' the exec environment at startup. I guess the `/opt/homebrew/bin` dir is added to your PATH via your `.zshrc` instead of via `.profile` (see https://linuxize.com/post/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/). So, incl. @kozina-adjacent's comment, I guess you have two options now for changing your exec-path (I assume these things work similar on macs).

Comment: @kozina-adjacent. After adding `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin")` to my .emacs file.  When I open a .py file now, I see this message: `Server pyright:79382/starting exited (check corresponding stderr buffer for details). Do you want to restart it? (y or n) y`.  I press 'y' and similar messages keep popping up (the number changes) until I press 'n'.

Comment: Please check the pyright error buffer to check the reason.

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas. I added the lsp-log to my original question (I hope this is what you are asking for)

Comment: I think the log is not the error buffer. Look for a buffer containing "stderr" in its name. And I guess also its name should start with "pyright".

Comment: @dalanicolai. I added the pyright stderr buffer in my original question

Comment: Okay. I don't know anything about macs, nor about npm/node, but in case no other user here has any better advice (which is unlikely :), then maybe the comments under the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465086/env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-in-mac) can help you out...

Comment: @dalanicolai. node is available in my emacs shell, so I don't think that's it, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `which node` in shell directs you where?

Comment: Well, this is not directly related, but you could check what happens by installing `pyright` with `pip`.

Comment: @kozina-adjacent.  `which node` outputs `/opt/homebrew/bin/node`

Comment: Just outta curiosity: if you also include `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/opt/homebrew/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))` in your init file, does that change anything for you?

Comment: @kozina-adjacent. That seems to have done the trick!  I added it under the line where I add homebrew to my exec path.

Comment: AWESOME. There might be a better way of going about this, but exactly how and where PATH is pulled form in emacs is always a bit of mystery to me and depends on your particular context. I have both of these lines in my init file. This package bills itself as a way out of this mess (https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) but I haven't investigated it much. At any rate, I'm glad you got it up and running :)